# Cordova build android:failed , what to do

Tags: node.js, cordova

i have used this from nodejs cli

```
cordova build android
```

it gives me this eror :-

```
(node:3352) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:3352) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

i cant detect whats wrong i am making a very basic hello world App
here is the code of my app

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>

</style>
<body>

    <h1>Hello World</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The best way to get started with a new app is by using the `cordova create Hello app.hello.world Hello` command, and add the platform afterwards.

Comment: i know that already , will a new app not give this error ?